# create list from a comma separated key in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have data set like this in MySQL:

```
table order
order_id   item_id        
1          A,B,C
2          B,D,E
```

and

```
table item 
item_id    item_name
A          Candy
B          Beer
C          Cookies
D          Jam
E          Cigarette
```

How can I return data like this:

```
order_id   item_id    item_name
1          A,B,C      Candy,Beer,Cookies
2          B,D,E      Beer,Cookies,Cigarette
```

Comment: Shouldn't row 2 be "Beer,Jam,Cigarette"?

Comment: this sounds like a healthy diet, whaddya think @vhu. Just once begging for non KEYWORD or RESERVED WORD questions to appear

Comment: The `order` table is poorly designed. You should consider having a row per item in the order, perhaps in an `order_items` table.

Comment: Yes. See normalisation

Comment: greetings @kekeskuya, I wrote up an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) recently on storing data in a junction table, and normalization, and sample statements to get to your data. Check it out some day and good luck !

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query-

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.item_id, GROUP_CONCAT(itm.item_name) 
FROM `order` AS o JOIN item AS itm ON FIND_IN_SET(itm.item_id,o.item_id) 
GROUP BY o.order_id;
```

Comment: but it is not optimized way you should use a junction table for both tables relation for better performance.

Answer (score -1):

Try This...

```
select o.order_id, o.item_id, GROUP_CONCAT(i.item_name SEPERATOR separator ',')
FROM order o
INNER JOIN item i ON on (find_in_set(i.item_id,o.item_id))
GROUP BY o.order_id
```