# mysql update one table from another

Tags: mysql

I have a massive database over over 2.7 million rows. It contains data on uk property prices.

The first Table is called PricePaid And has a column called Price and Loc4.

Now I am trying to get the average for each year grouped by loc4 and update another tabel called PricePaidByCounty.

I have created this SQL statement :

```
INSERT PricePaidByCounty (County, Avg2013)
SELECT Loc4,
Avg(Price) as AvgPrice2013 FROM PricePaid WHERE Date Like '%2013%'
Group BY Loc4
```

This works fine for inserting initial row but I want to use an update statement instead as I will need to run this SQL query each month.

Can anyone show me how to change this Insert into an update.

I am doing this as I need to quickly display average house price for each location by year. And the Database is that big I dont want to do this on the flu

Thanks

Comment: You can use JOIN and subselects inside your update-statements

Comment: this database schema is assumed to be poorly designed is all I can say. The fact that you have a column called Avg2013, and doing a `like`

Comment: the way to do it is to have a Junction table, and in it have avg information by year. and a `composite` on a generic column named something like `theYear` (along with another column). See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163/1816093). He wanted to do data as CSV in one column. You want to add columns per year (same difference bad design)

Comment: As such you have fast access via joins and index use, versus using a `like` which is a no no

Answer (score 1):

You can update your table using following query using insert ... on duplicate key update statement (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO PricePaidByCounty (County, Avg2013)
SELECT Loc4, Avg(Price) as AvgPrice2013 
FROM PricePaid 
WHERE Date Like '%2013%' 
GROUP BY Loc4
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Avg2013=AvgPrice2013
```

For this to work you need to make sure that a set of (County, Avg2013)  is defined as unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like table `PricePaidByCounty` needs three columns `Country`, `Year` and `Average` so that while updating by year you can choose to update by particular year. Then the query would be like:

```
UPDATE PricePaidByCounty ppbc JOIN (SELECT Loc4,
Avg(Price) as AvgPrice FROM PricePaid WHERE Date Like '%2013%'
Group BY Loc4) ap SET ppbc.Average = ap.AvgPrice WHERE ppbc.Country = ap.Loc4 AND ppbc.Year = 2013;
```

This can be enhanced to group by `Loc4` and `Year` and directly update to `PricePaidByCounty`. It may run for days as you have multiple records. :D