# companies er model for different countries

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, erd

I want to build a ER-model for companies.
Some fields for companies are the same, like the `name`, `legal_address` and others, but some fields are defined based on the country, where the company is registered.

For example if we take `Russia`, the company should have fields like `inn`, `ogrn`, etc.. (don't matter the names).
If we will take another country - the company will have another set of fields.

I need an advice of how to plan (architect) this.

Any ideas would be great.

At the moment I have this done:

```
[locations]
id
country
city
lat
lng
zip_code

[companies]
id
location_id
name
director
legal_address
actual_address

[company_russia]
id
company_id
inn
kpp
ogrn
stat_codes
reg_number_fss
reg_number_pfr
```

But I think there will be problems joining the tables and that each other country requires a separate table - is not a good approach.

Comment: Depends on how're you going to use it, as usual: the number of countries? Lookups/updates frequency? Option to store all the additional data in another DB? You might want to look into schema-less approach with [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660866/native-json-support-in-mysql-5-7-what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-json-data-type) datatype, for example.

Comment: [_More_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) on using JSON for an EAV schema design.