# Using MySQL to store image paths in JSON vs rows/column?

Tags: mysql, json, database-design

I am looking to make an app where people have 20 different categories of pictures they can post, and for each category you are allowed up to 20 pictures.

If I were to have 100,000 users, that's a huge amount of rows that I could have to query from to get an single users photos.

My question is, is JSON a faster or slower alternative?

Each user would have maybe, 20 columns, each with a JSON blob of the photos in each, or alternatively, a single column with a JSON blob, containing all photos inside their respective categories.

Each photo will have to have the ability to be deleted, or updated, along with some additional information such us upload date, etc...

What are the differences, what is your recommendation?

thank you!

Comment: Searching and updating JSON values is far less efficient than searching or updating rows if you have an appropriate index on those rows.

Comment: I would have 40 million rows.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean an appropriate index of those rows? I am not sure if its possible to answer my question how I'd like it to be, but simply put. Is it better to search through 100,000,000 individual rows for 20 results. or is it better to search 1.000.000 rows for a column then search the JSON object for its results?

Comment: Learn the basics of relational & SQL optimization/implementation by query engines per textbooks in general & DBMS manual in particular--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. Appropriate research is expected for questions. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching performance you should opt for indexing them rather than saving them as JSON values. should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33661590)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would not give this question much attention.  But you suggest 100K users, each with up to 400 URLs.  This gets bulky with either approach.  But first, see whether you must use Plan B:

Plan A:  If you will *never* be using MySQL to search based on the content of a column, then you can put whatever you want into it.  If the *client* wants to pick apart the contents of a column, then, sure, use JSON (or whatever) to make it easier.  And you could save space by compressing the column in the client and using a `BLOB` instead of `JSON`.

Plan B:  If, on the other hand, you want MySQL to pick rows based on some part of a column, then do *not* hide it in the middle of a column.  Nor should you have 20 columns for 20 widgets.

If you decide to go with plan A, then there is another issue that *may* be of importance.  When you have a bulky column(s) in a table (and it sounds like 400 URLs will be bulky), that columns will *probably* be stored "off-record".  This implies an extra disk hit to fetch it.  So, beware of using `SELECT *` when you don't need that column; that is, spell out the columns you *do* need.

(There may be more tips; please provide more details on your app.)