# MySQL Tables column inheritance dynamically

Tags: mysql, inheritance, structure

I don't know if this is possible but I'll explain what I need.

What I've got:
- Table1: A users table
- Table2: A table which contains items definitions
- Table3: A table which stores for each user, amounts of items (defined in previous table)

With this tables structure, what I need to achieve is that when I add a row in **Table2** (items definitions), automatically **Table3** (users items) updates according to **Table2** columns.

Example:

[image]

If I deleted a row in **Table2**, this would be the action:

[image]
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: look into triggers. And restructure table3 into a [Junction Table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163/). Your table3 is de-normalized. What are you going to keep doing, adding new columns to table3 constantly?

Comment: @Drew That's what I want to avoid. A two table maintenance. The point is to add rows to Table2 and automatically those rows will become columns in Table3. That way I can count how many items have each user (as an example). I'll check Junction Table definition. Thanks.

Comment: If you are saying that you want to add a row to t2, and the textual value of a column in the new row becomes a column name in t3, then I say this is about the poorest of concepts. And I wish you luck with that (and any peer blessing) :)  But who cares about peer blessings half the time. They just want to do it their way

Comment: @Drew The first line of my question makes clear that I'm asking this because I don't know how to achieve this (yes, my SQL knowledge is low).  I need a response that guides me how to do it, not a "sarcastically reply". Thanks again.

Comment: I have a Junction Table link in comment line 1. I wrote it to help people. No sarcasm intended. Just a reflection on what people tend to do anyway.

Comment: @Drew I'll study your answer as it's complex, but I'm sure It will help me. Thanks.

Comment: my pleasure. Bounce your drafts by us