# Tables in MySQL with more than two dimensions

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am an beginner-to-intermediate level programmer and am trying to re-design a MySQL database for someone.  It has the following attributes:

- Shows start and end times for alcohol sales in an area
- Times vary by day of week
- Times vary for beer and wine vs. all types of alcohol (liquor, too).
- Times vary by off-premises (i.e.: liquor store) vs. on-premises (i.e.: bar)

I tried researching this but couldn't find a clear answer.  Currently he one huge table.  Example columns are:

- offwedbwstart (off-premises, Wednesday, beer & wine only, starting time)
- onfriallend (on-premises, Friday, all alcohol types, end time)

I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to organize this table using arrays as entries or by using multiple tables.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Or is this simply a matter of preference?  I'm also worried about the efficiency of using multiple tables.

Thank you!

---

Revision in response to comment (more detailed explanation):

Here's are the fields of the original table which I'm tasked with revising.  It is all one big table:

`id` BIGINT(9) NOT NULL, - Primary Key
 `state` TINYTEXT NULL, -
   Full State Name
 `county` TINYTEXT NULL, - Full County Name
   `place` TINYTEXT NULL, - Full Place Name
 `placetype` TINYINT(2)
   NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Is the Place a County, City, etc.
 `format`
   TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Not sure
 `multname` TINYINT(1)
   NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Does the place have multiple names
   `multcounty` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Does the place cross
   multiple counties
 `population` INT(8) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   Population
 `offsunallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   Off-Premsies (convenience stores, liquor stores, etc.), Sunday, All
   types of alcohol (including liquor), Start Time (military time
   integer, hours and minutes past midnight)
 `offsunallend`
   SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Sunday, All types of
   alcohol, End Time (military time integer, hours and minutes past
   midnight) 
 `offsunbwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   Off-Premises, Sunday, Beer and Wine only,Start Time
 `offsunbwend`
   SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Sunday, Beer and Wine
   only,End Time
 `offmonallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   Off-Premises, Monday, All types of alcohol, Start Time
   `offmonallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Monday,
   All types of alcohol, End Time
 `offmonbwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL
   DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Monday, Beer and Wine only,Start
   Time
 `offmonbwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises,
   Monday, Beer and Wine only,End Time
 `offtueallstart` SMALLINT(4)
   NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Tuesday, All types of alcohol,
   Start Time
 `offtueallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   Off-Premises, Tuesday, All types of alcohol, End Time
   `offtuebwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises,
   Tuesday, Beer and Wine only,Start Time
 `offtuebwend` SMALLINT(4)
   NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Tuesday, Beer and Wine only,End
   Time
 `offwedallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   Off-Premises, Wednesday, All types of alcohol, Start Time
   `offwedallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises,
   Wednesday, All types of alcohol, End Time
 `offwedbwstart`
   SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Wednesday, Beer and
   Wine only,Start Time
 `offwedbwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   - Off-Premises, Wednesday, Beer and Wine only,End Time
 `offthuallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises,
   Thursday, All types of alcohol, Start Time
 `offthuallend`
   SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Thursday, All types of
   alcohol, End Time
 `offthubwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   - Off-Premises, Thursday, Beer and Wine only,Start Time
 `offthubwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises,
   Thursday, Beer and Wine only,End Time
 `offfriallstart`
   SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Friday, All types of
   alcohol, Start Time
 `offfriallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   - Off-Premises, Friday, All types of alcohol, End Time
 `offfribwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises,
   Friday, Beer and Wine only,Start Time
 `offfribwend` SMALLINT(4)
   NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Friday, Beer and Wine only,End
   Time
 `offsatallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   Off-Premises, Saturday, All types of alcohol, Start Time
   `offsatallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises,
   Saturday, All types of alcohol, End Time
 `offsatbwstart`
   SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - Off-Premises, Saturday, Beer and
   Wine only,Start Time
 `offsatbwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   - Off-Premises, Saturday, Beer and Wine only,End Time
 `onsunallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies (bars,
   restaraunts, etc.), Sunday, All types of alcohol, Start Time
   `onsunallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Sunday,
   All types of alcohol, End Time
 `onsunbwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL
   DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Sunday, Beer and Wine only,Start
   Time
 `onsunbwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies,
   Sunday, Beer and Wine only,End Time
 `onmonallstart` SMALLINT(4)
   NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Monday, All types of alcohol, Start
   Time
 `onmonallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies,
   Monday, All types of alcohol, End Time
 `onmonbwstart` SMALLINT(4)
   NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Monday, Beer and Wine only,Start
   Time
 `onmonbwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies,
   Monday, Beer and Wine only,End Time
 `ontueallstart` SMALLINT(4)
   NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Tuesday, All types of alcohol,
   Start Time
 `ontueallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   On-Premsies, Tuesday, All types of alcohol, End Time
   `ontuebwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Tuesday,
   Beer and Wine only,Start Time
 `ontuebwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL
   DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Tuesday, Beer and Wine only,End Time
   `onwedallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies,
   Wednesday, All types of alcohol, Start Time
 `onwedallend`
   SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Wednesday, All types of
   alcohol, End Time
 `onwedbwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   On-Premsies, Wednesday, Beer and Wine only,Start Time
   `onwedbwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Wednesday,
   Beer and Wine only,End Time
 `onthuallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL
   DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Thursday, All types of alcohol, Start
   Time
 `onthuallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies,
   Thursday, All types of alcohol, End Time
 `onthubwstart`
   SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Thursday, Beer and Wine
   only,Start Time
 `onthubwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   On-Premsies, Thursday, Beer and Wine only,End Time
   `onfriallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Friday,
   All types of alcohol, Start Time
 `onfriallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL
   DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Friday, All types of alcohol, End
   Time
 `onfribwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies,
   Friday, Beer and Wine only,Start Time
 `onfribwend` SMALLINT(4)
   NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Friday, Beer and Wine only,End
   Time
 `onsatallstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -
   On-Premsies, Saturday, All types of alcohol, Start Time
   `onsatallend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Saturday,
   All types of alcohol, End Time
 `onsatbwstart` SMALLINT(4) NULL
   DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies, Saturday, Beer and Wine only,Start
   Time
 `onsatbwend` SMALLINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, - On-Premsies,
   Saturday, Beer and Wine only,End Time
 `offexceptions` TEXT NULL,
   - Off-Premises exceptions as a note
 `onexceptions` TEXT NULL, - On-Premises exceptions as a not
 `source` TEXT NULL, - Where did
   this information come from?
 `sourcelink` TINYTEXT NULL, - Link
   for information
 `timezone` TINYTEXT NULL, - TimeZone (EST, for
   example)
 `notes` TEXT NULL - Other miscellaneous notes

As you can see this is kind of a data nightmare.  I've been reading up on how to organize this better and some problems that come up are crossing over midnight for sales, and there is another problem of multiple days of the week having the same start and close times, to which I thought I could create a table that simply had the fields:

- Start Day (weekday, integer representation)
- End Day (weekday, integer representation)
- Start Time (hours past midnight that morning, integer representation)
- End Time (hours past midnight that morning, integer representation)

Please feel free to make any suggestions for a schema.

Thank you!

Comment: [Junction tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) or association tables. No arrays in columns. Data normalization. Indexes used in queries versus wishful thinking

Comment: We need to know a bit more about what is actually stored in that database. It's probably a simple task normalizing the tables and queries, but from the samples you've provided we can't tell. So aside from the attributes, what actually goes into that database, and what do you seek to extract from it?

Comment: Revised the post.  Hope that clears things up a bit.  I'm seeking to extract the start and end times for the sales of alcohol in a given municipality for any given day of the week.  There are variations in beer and wine vs. liquor and on-premises vs. off-premises purchases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple tables is one of the major strengths of using a *relational database*.  Otherwise, go ahead and use a spreadsheet program instead.  :-0

One flaw I see in that database structure is that finding, for example, Thursday's information requires knowing the specific field name of four fields.  It would be better for the field names to be generic—no day of week in them—and add one field for the day of the week.  That reduces the number of fields by a factor of almost seven:  28 fields are reduced to 5.

There might be some further data normalization possible with the geography fields, but it is tough to know without knowing more about how that is used.  If there is a lot of interfacing to the field names, you already have a heap of work just to reducing it for day of week.  Try revising the schema just for that much and you'll probably know enough to decide if more needs to be done or if it would be more work than it is worth.

Comment: I sincerely wish to emphasize that I'm re-doing this for a lawyer who treated it like a spreadsheet and I told him that.  Now it's my job to re-design it.  I don't think it's anything that some PL/SQL scripts can't repair, but I want to have a solid schema first.  Thank you for the DOW integer suggestion, though.  I will employ it.

Comment: I have designed a schema that employs your suggestions and my research.  I have posed another question related to the geography fields, which are incredibly complicated.