# MySQL procedures comma delimited string compare with triger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

i have a mysql column which hold comma delimited value, and external program intert/update data to that column, how can  i make trigger to compare which value added to comma delimited string or which data remove?

lets say column1 has data a,b,c,d and external program add e or remove d from column1, how to detect which value was added or removed?

Comment: this is a fantastic example of why not to save your data like this. Use [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) or association tables to store data properly. In addition to the sanity of doing such, you get *index* performance