# Different views for different users

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, soft-delete

Say I have a database with 3 tables: `Stream`, `Tag` and `Post`

- Stream has one tag. Multiple streams can have the same tag.
- Stream is owned by one user.
- A tag has many posts.
- Different tags can have the same post.
- Each user that opens his stream gets it's posts (via the tag) and can delete (or hide) the posts he doesn't want to see (but only for him, not for others).

What would be the appropriate way to achieve this? Obviously I'll need some kind of *soft-delete* flag on posts. I currently have 2 ideas in mind:

1. Create another table that will act as the view of the stream with columns `stream_id`, `post_id` and `is_deleted`
2. Add `deleted` column to `Stream` that holds a JSON array of deleted posts' ids. The problem with this approach is querying based on is_deleted state.

Are there any better ways?

Note: Currently, I need `Tag` to stay in it's own table, rather than storing it as text in a column in `Stream`

Comment: The second "solution" brings more problems than it solves. Forget about it.

Comment: check out my [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163). They connect tableA to tableB. In yours, have your tailored columns.

Comment: Why do you want to delete a post? You say *"can delete (or ban) the posts he doesn't want to see (but only for him, not for others)."* The user doesn't delete a post, they only remove the post from their stream. A stream has many posts and a post can appear in more than one stream. This is a many-to-many relationship that has to be implemented using a link table. When the user deletes a post you only need to delete a row from this table. You can also add an "is_deleted" column to this table and set "is_deleted = 1" for soft delete if you want to allow the user to undo the deletion...

Comment: ... A better solution for this situation (when the deletions can be undone) is to move the row into another table (that contains only the posts deleted by each user).

Comment: @axiac My bad. I've tried to simplify my real use case by omitting a mid-table. Sorry about that! Actually, `Stream` has `Tag` (currently just one per stream, so many-to-one) and `Tag` has posts.. so the many-to-many relationship is between the `Tag` and `Post`.

Comment: @Drew so basically another many-to-many table

Comment: It would seem to suggest that :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a new table with the columns post_id, is_deleted & user_id. 
In this way you can manage it easily or else it will be hectic work as per your options are considered. 
The table name will be like cross reference table ex: user_deleted_posts_xref