# PHP SQL how i can get total number of rows when using CASE and table JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, search

After googling I founded that `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` can result the total number of rows available in table before applying `limit`.

But I have very **complex sql query with php** when searching for some text in database and also want to know **total available result in database**.

```
SELECT    i.name 'title',i.add_time 'time',round(i.price) 'price',round(i.new_price) 'new_price',
          s.store_address 'address', s.name 'name'
FROM      store_items i,stores s
WHERE     i.store_id = s.store_id 
AND       (i.name like '%samsung glaxy%' AND 
          i.name like '%samsung%' AND i.name like '%galaxy%' 
          OR i.name like '%samsung%' OR i.name like '%galaxy%')
          ORDER BY
          CASE WHEN i.name like '%%'
          AND i.name like '%samsung%' AND i.name like '%galaxy%' THEN 1
          WHEN i.name like '%samsung%' OR i.name like '%galaxy%' THEN 2
          END,
          i.price ASC
          LIMIT 0,25"
```

How it can be possible to get total number of available rows by matching the following results.

Is it can be possible by using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` sql function. or some other way is available in `PHP`.

Comment: do you mean the count of what you have above for your exact query (up to 25) ?

Comment: I want to count all matched rows in my database but I am limiting 25 rows to show data and also want to show the user how much result are available in database, I am using `pagination`

Comment: Do you want the total rows returned from your above query

Comment: Or do you want it without regards to pagination

Comment: I want the total rows returned from my query before using `LIMIT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will present the below. Hopefully you can find something helpful. Your query is no different, just bigger. Look into [`found_rows()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) perhaps. Or a derived table like `xDerived`.

Also, the [Obligatory Reading](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) of the Percona article.

```
create table n1
(   thing int not null
);
insert n1(thing) values 
(1),(3),(1),(1),(17),(1),(17),(11);
-- 8 rows inserted

select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS thing from n1 where thing<12 order by thing limit 0,2;
select found_rows() as foundRows;
+-----------+
| foundRows |
+-----------+
|         6 |
+-----------+

select count(*) as theCount 
from 
(   select thing from n1 where thing<12 order by thing limit 0,2 
) xDerived; 
+----------+
| theCount |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
```

Comment: I want to use only one query which I showed above and don't want to use it twice.

Comment: I want I want I want. Not much more I can give you.

Comment: Your case stmt is irrelevant, and the query is not complex. The issue is wanting too much from a programming environment that does not please out of the box. A stored proc needs to be written with an `OUT` parameter. Then about after an hour or more of debugging where the guy doesn't know how to do that, it may work for him. But we are free servants here. So, well, I guess tinker away or make an extra call or two. This topic is well known by those who have struggled with it; I estimate probably 10M people worldwide.

Comment: so then should I use another call to database for count?

Comment: And I wouldn't dwell too much on making one call. Because the performance of your query is going to be awful anyway with large data and a `LIKE`. People use Full text search and [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) who seek performance and the use of indexes.

Comment: I would use another call. Some people would say why bother knowing the count of the max set, just use what you get with pagination until the last requestion is <pageSize (say 50 or 100)

Comment: I need to head out to help someone. Good luck my friend.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot and gave me your importent time