# Join multiple fields to multiple rows of a table

Tags: mysql

I created a table called `products` that looks something like this:

```
+----+-----------------+------------------------------+
| id | name            | another information          |
+----+-----------------+------------------------------+
|  1 | product1        |                            a |
|  2 | product2        |                            b |
|  3 | product3        |                            c |
|  4 | product4        |                            d |
|  5 | product5        |                            e |
+----+-----------------+------------------------------+
```

And another one called `product_list` that looks like this:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | product_1       | product_2       | product_3       |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1 |               1 |               2 |            NULL |
|  2 |            NULL |               2 |            NULL |
|  3 |               3 |               4 |               1 |
|  4 |            NULL |            NULL |            NULL |
|  5 |               1 |               4 |               3 |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Now I want to `JOIN product_list` with `products` ON every `product_` with the id of `products`, it would be something like this:

```
+----+-----------------------------+
| id | product_list                | 
+----+-----------------------------+
|  1 | product1,product2           |        
|  2 | product2                    |
|  3 | product3,product4,product1  |
|  4 | NULL                        | 
|  5 | product1,product4,product3  |
+----+-----------------------------+
```

I do many tests but no one works. I think that this code is the most similar to what I need:

```
SELECT 
pl.id,
GROUP_CONCAT(p.name)
FROM products AS p
JOIN product_list AS pl
ON(
   (pl.product_1 = p.id OR pl.product_1 IS NULL)
   AND (pl.product_2 = p.id OR pl.product_2 IS NULL)
   AND (pl.product_3 = p.id OR pl.product_3 IS NULL)
)
GROUP BY pl.id
```

Comment: What if there's a 4th product?

Comment: This is one of the problems of the code that I want to solve :P

Comment: please do a better job of db design

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163

Comment: Yes. See normalisation. Then normalise your design.