# MySQL incremental columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below:

```
ID|Prototype_A|Prototype_B|Prototype_C|Prototype_D|
---------------------------------------------------
1 |Fast381A   |Blue4812   | Green7181 | White4812 |
---------------------------------------------------
2 |Slow841C   |Orange8312 | null      | null      |
---------------------------------------------------
3 |Plane281K  | null      | null      | null      |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I need my query to return all non null prototypes for that ID.
so for example:

1 : Fast381A,Blue4812,Green7181,White4812

2 : Slow841C,Orange8312

3 : Plane281K

Is there a way to wildcard select all columns like `select(Prototype_*)` or should I setup my table in a different format?

For example I've been taught this type of structure is bad practice:

```
ID|Prototypes|
---------------------------------------------------
1 |Fast381A,Blue4812,Green7181,White4812 
---------------------------------------------------
2 |Slow841C,Orange8312
---------------------------------------------------
3 |Plane281K
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Look into [EAV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) (I wouldn't but maybe you want to). Or normalize your data with [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) or association tables

Comment: As for your top question, it would require something like a stored proc. It would go sense the schema structure, construct dynamic sql into a PREPARE, and execute it. And it would be slow due to the overhead.

Comment: What about prototype e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns.  If you want to combine the non-NULL values into a single column, I would recommend `concat_ws()`:

```
select id,
       concat_ws(',', Prototype_A, Prototype_B, Prototype_C, Prototype_D)
from t;
```

This ignores the `NULL` values.  The query returns two columns, one is a list of prototypes.

And, the answer to your question is "Yes".  You should consider changing your data structure.  Having multiple columns storing the same thing, with just an index identifying them usually means that you want a separate table, with one row per id and per prototype.

EDIT:

You want a table like this:

```
create table ModelPrototypes (
    ModelProtypeId int primary key auto_increment,
    ModelId int not null,
    ProtoTypeChar char(1),
    Prototype varchar(255)
);
```

Then you would populate it with values like:

```
1   A    Fast381A
1   B    Blue4812
1   C    Green7181
1   D    White4812
```

I'm not sure if `PrototypeChar` is really needed, but the information is in your table.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the separate table because i'm envisioning a table with an ever increasing number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to wildcard select columns.

What you could do:

Setup your table as

```
ID, Prototype_type, Prototype_name
```

Then use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(Prototype_name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table GROUP BY Prototype_name
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Should I setup my table in a different format?"`

Yes. Your table might look as follows:

```
ID Prototype_Code Prototype 
------------------------------
 1 A              Fast381A  
 1 B              Blue4812  
 1 C              Green7181 
 1 D              White4812 
 2 A              Slow841C  
 2 B              Orange8312
 3 A              Plane281K
```