# Efficient SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: TableX Data]

On getting random associative array pairs from fields **product_option_id:product_option_value_id**  like {"230":"23","228":"19"}, I have to get the minimum **quantity** from the respective rows in the above TableX.

Currently, I query the database through PHP based on each pair, and store their quantity. i.e.- If there are 3 pairs, I query the database 3 times based on each pair to get the 3 quantities. Then I loop through the quantities to get the least one.

If the random {product_option_id:product_option_value_id} pairs are {"230":"23","228":"19"}, can you make an efficient SQL statement that gets the minimum **quantity**.

I have tried

```
SELECT quantity FROM TableX 
WHERE product_option_id=variable_product_option_id 
  AND product_option_value_id=variable_product_option_value_id
```

I run this in a PHP for loop for all the pair values. I store the quanity, and get the least one through PHP

Comment: [normalize your data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163)

Comment: The following code is based on my personal situation: `SELECT quantity FROM " . DB_PREFIX ."product_option_value WHERE product_option_id=".$key." AND product_option_value_id=".$value." AND subtract=1"`. I run this in a PHP for loop for all the pair values. I store the quanity, and get the least one through PHP.

Comment: In future, use the edit link to include extra info on your question. Nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Can you give an example?

Comment: @kbball The basic info is the rows are determined through the pair values of product_option_id & product_option_value_id. Then we have to get the minimum quantity based on the rows.

Comment: You want the minimum quantity of the "pair"? Meaning the smaller value of the two? Or you want to sum the two? Are you looking for a minimum per row or for the table? Based on the data you have above, what is your expected result?

Comment: hi @kbball. saw your comment just now. got the answer from Izo. thanks.

Comment: See the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a query like this one:

```
select product_option_id, product_option_value_id, min(quantity)
    from product_option_value
    where (product_option_id = 230 and product_option_value_id = 43)
        or (product_option_id = 228 and product_option_value_id = 49)
    group by product_option_id, product_option_value_id;
```

In practice:

```
> create table product_option_value(product_option_id int, product_option_value_id int, quantity int);

> insert into product_option_value values
>     (230, 43, 2),
>     (230, 32, 1),
>     (228, 49, 1),
>     (228, 50, 0),
>     (229, 50, 1),
>     (229, 49, 1),
>     (230, 43, 8),
>     (230, 32, 9),
>     (228, 49, 11),
>     (228, 50, 10),
>     (229, 50, 5),
>     (229, 49, 4);

> select product_option_id, product_option_value_id, min(quantity)
>     from product_option_value
>     where (product_option_id = 230 and product_option_value_id = 43)
>         or (product_option_id = 228 and product_option_value_id = 49)
>     group by product_option_id, product_option_value_id;
+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| product_option_id | product_option_value_id | min(quantity) |
+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| 228               | 49                      | 1             |
| 230               | 43                      | 2             |
+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

You should also quote the query parameters properly. Using constructs like `...product_option_id=".$key."...` (excerpt from your example from the comments) is error-prone, as `$key` may contain anything, like [Little Boby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Edit: To get just a single minimum for all such groups, you just drop the group by and the grouping columns, like this:

```
> select min(quantity)
>     from product_option_value
>     where (product_option_id = 230 and product_option_value_id = 43)
>         or (product_option_id = 228 and product_option_value_id = 49);
+---------------+
| min(quantity) |
+---------------+
| 1             |
+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Izo. Although your solution wasn't exactly I was looking for, I now know how to handle the issue. In your excellent example, the result is 2 rows with quantity of 1 & 2. I just wanted to get a single row with the minimum quantity i.e.- 1.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case it's even easier. I updated my answer to cover this use-case as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try following one query to get your result.

To get this kind of result `product_option_id:product_option_value_id` you should use `CONCAT` function of MYSQL.

```
SELECT CONCAT(product_option_id,':',product_option_value_id) 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE subtract = 1 
GROUP BY product_option_id 
ORDER BY product_option_value_id ASC
```

Also you can put additional where conditions.

Please try this.