# Searching for number in mysql column with CSV

Tags: mysql, csv

SELECT DISTINCT example_type FROM Table_name WHERE 80 IN (example_type);

The values I'm using are 66 and 80.

The values for the column are sometimes "66,80" and sometimes "80,66".

If it is a search for 80, it will only return a match if the column is "80,66" (or "80").

If it is a search for 66, it will only return a match if the column is "66,80" (or "66").

The column type is set to TEXT.

The following works as expected: (both are a match)

....WHERE 80 IN (66,80)...

....WHERE 80 IN (80,66)...

I'd like to keep the contents of the column as CSV.

What do I need to do to the MySQL query to get it work no matter the order of the CSV?

Comment: I would bite the bullet and save your data right. Whether it be [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) with many to many, or association tables. Otherwise, development and performance can be a nightmare.

Comment: It looks like I found a fix. CSV simplifies the queries and the CSV can be easily sent to and from "select" form elements.

Comment: The problem with that is non-use of indexes.

Comment: The special cases are rare and it seems to run fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT example_type FROM Table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET(80, example_type);

This is based on the final code:

```
        WHERE ...a.is_special = 1
            AND (a.foo_list = '' OR FIND_IN_SET($foo_id, a.foo_list))
            AND (a.bar_list = '' OR FIND_IN_SET($bar_id, a.bar_list))
            AND (a.baz_list = '' OR FIND_IN_SET($baz_id, a.baz_list))";
```

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can use the following where clause:

```
 WHERE column_name like '%80%'
```

If your two queries are right, then you can use union clause in mysql

```
 SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (your first condition)
 UNION
 SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (your second condition)
```