# Mysql - right data field type for list of integers

Tags: mysql, varchar

I want to store a set of integers in my column (ids_set):

```
id   ids_set
1    1,2,3,4...76
2    4,5,8...12
```

What is a best field type for this - varchar or text?
Thanks.

Comment: insert them as separate rows.

Comment: Do you mean separate rows or separate columns? Like id, ids_set1, ids_set2, etc..

Comment: Normalise your schema

Comment: dont use a sql server if you do this. Use index cards or paper. See [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is better not store int separed by comma  ..anyway depend of the lenght  of your string  ... below 255 char varchar,  above is better text

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html

```
char  - varchar The length can be any value from 0 to 255. 

BLOB, TEXT   2^16
```

Comment: There's also `TINYTEXT`/`TINYBLOB` with same limits as varchar. What about those? And anyways, why are we suggesting the OP to store numbers as strings? They'd later come back asking to write a `COUNT`/`SUM` query using the ids stored as strings. :/

Comment: @hjpotter92   your comment is correct  .. in my answer i suggest that is not the better way store int like string  and sure  .. there are several string type but the concepts is related  essentially to the length ..

Comment: Typos aside, you can pretty much disregard everything after the first 8 words of this answer.