# Multiple rows values to one cell in MySQL

Tags: mysql, denormalization

I would like to ask for your help in order to achieve the following 
I have a table that the id column may have the same id on multiple rows which corresponds to different values on another column like the example bellow

TABLE #1

```
+-----+---------+
| id1 | value1  | 
+-----+---------+
|  1  |    1    | 
+-----+---------+
|  1  |    2    | 
+-----+---------+
|  1  |    3    | 
+-----+---------+
|  2  |    4    | 
+-----+---------+
|  2  |    5    | 
+-----+---------+
|  2  |    6    | 
+-----+---------+
```

Based on id column I need the values that corresponds to the same id to be inputted in the same cell separated by a comma like the following example

Those need to be updated on another table

TABLE #2

```
+-----+---------+
| id2 | value2  | 
+-----+---------+
|  1  |  1,2,3  | 
+-----+---------+
|  2  |  4,5,6  | 
+-----+---------+
```

How can this be done?

Comment: use `group_concat()` to achieve this in a result set but never save your data this way. See [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) if you are ever entertaining the idea of doing so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason for denormalizing your data and violating First Normal Form (1NF)? You shouldn't do that - it's better to have the data normalized. You could create a view if it's required to present data this way.

---

Anyways, since this answer should also include a solution, here's one:

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT id1, GROUP_CONCAT(value1 ORDER BY value1 ASC SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table1
GROUP BY id1
```

To update results in other table where ids match:

```
UPDATE table2 a
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT id1, GROUP_CONCAT(value1 ORDER BY value1 ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS value2
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY id1
  ) b ON a.id1 = b.id2
SET a.value2 = b.value2
```

Comment: A valid reason for denormalizing like this could be the use of paging in an application. Example: I want to see results by 'id1' in the query above - 20 records at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use group_concat

```
select id, group_concat(value1) as value2
from table1
group by id
```