# How to count sum of three columns MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have three columns with names:

```
 projectNo| process | procLeader | procCheker  |     Stuff     |
----------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+
 16090001 | ANM     | ben        | barry       | bob, bart, bok| 
 16090001 | BLD     | anton      | kirill      | kart, ali     |
```

What I want to is to count procLeader, procChecker, stuff columns assigned to projectNo. I managed to count each column by using query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(procLeader) AS `ld`, 
    COUNT(procChecker) AS `ch`, 
    SUM((LENGTH(stuff) - LENGTH(REPLACE(stuff,",","")) + 1)) AS `st` 
FROM `process` 
WHERE projectNo=16090001;
```

I get

```
 ld| ch | st |
---+----+----+
  2|   2|   5|
```

I need something like 'total' table

How I can sum this values? or maybe use another method?

Comment: SO is littered with questions like this from people who forgot to normalize their databse.

Comment: [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163)

Comment: And they think their queries run the same speed

Comment: Not even 1NF :0

Comment: I guess, you are trying to sum up the ch and st column. Is it?

Comment: @AT-2016 all three columns: ld,ch,st

Comment: See my post and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(procLeader) AS `ld`, COUNT(procCheker) AS `ch`, 
SUM((LENGTH(stuff) - LENGTH(REPLACE(stuff,",","")) + 1)) AS `st` ,
(
   COUNT(procLeader) + 
    COUNT(procCheker) +
    SUM((LENGTH(stuff) - LENGTH(REPLACE(stuff,",","")) + 1)) 
 ) As `Total` 
 FROM `process` WHERE projectNo=16090001
```

Please let us know if you have any concerns or que.

Comment: getting this error `Unknown column 'procCheker' in 'field list`

Comment: oh the thing it not proCheker, there is a typo, should be procChecker. and it works thanks.

Comment: at table structure you mentioned  'procCheker' and in query you mentioned  'procChecker'. Query Edited. Thank U

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query and it worked:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(procLeader) AS `ld`, COUNT(procChecker) AS `ch`, 
SUM((LENGTH(stuff) - LENGTH(REPLACE(stuff,",","")) + 1)) AS `st` ,
(
   COUNT(procLeader) + 
   COUNT(procChecker) +
   SUM((LENGTH(stuff) - LENGTH(REPLACE(stuff,",","")) + 1)) 
) As `Total` 
FROM `process` WHERE projectNo = 16090001
```

Output:

```
Id - ch - st - Total
2  - 2  - 5  - 9
```

Comment: now get problem, it works perfectly in phpmyadmin sql query, but when I put query in php code it shows `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' ` Here is query in php `$result3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT (COUNT(procLeader) + COUNT(procChecker) + SUM((LENGTH(stuff) - LENGTH(REPLACE(stuff,",","")) + 1)) ) AS total FROM process WHERE projectNo = '$projectNo'");` Why so?

Comment: Oh i got the problem, nvm

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand question, but if you want to count characters, did you try char_length and concat ?

```
SELECT char_length(concat(procleader, proccheker, REPLACE(stuff,',',''))) FROM process WHERE projectNo=16090001
```

Comment: I dont want to count characters, I need to count names