# mySQL - FIND_IN_SET() doesn't find the value

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying to get posts which includes a spesific tag.

**The tag row content**

```
,iphone|1468338028,,android|1468338028,,blackberry|1468338028,
```

**query**

```
SELECT * FROM shares WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tag, 'iphone') > 0 ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 10
```

What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: The actual problem is your table design. Can you change it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Could you please explain more ?

Comment: Your tag is `iphone|1468338028` and you look for `iphone`. That does not match

Comment: Is there anyway to use something like ,*|*, preg match ?

Comment: [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) when the answer isn't unfortunately no anymore. Who knows, you might even get to use indexes

Comment: The MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function operates according to the specification laid out in the MySQL Reference Manual. And since the value 'iphone' does not appear in the set, the return is what we expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tag is `iphone|1468338028` and you look for `iphone`. That does not match.
Replace the `|` with `,` to separate the values.

```
SELECT * FROM shares 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(replace(tag, '|', ','), 'iphone') > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was thinking. One question, if there is an empty space, does it make problems ?

Comment: I'd say yes, that is a problem. Try to avoid that.

Comment: Can't I use trim() in your query ?

Comment: Depends on where the space is exactly. Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use `LIKE "%text%"`, if you're not required to use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

```
SELECT * FROM shares 
WHERE tag LIKE "%iphone%"
ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 10
```

Above snippet should achieve the same, thus avoiding replacing and trimming issues.