# how to insert same columns from second columns values mysql

Tags: mysql

**table 1**

```
id | sub1           | sub2                | sub3
1  | KK Nagar       | Alwartirunagar      |   
1  | Valasaravakkam | Nandambakkam        | Ramapuram
1  | Porur          | Meenambakkam        | Ashok Nagar
1  | Anna Nagar     | Kodambakkam         | Nungambakkam
2  | West Mambalam  | Virugambakkam       | T Nagar
2  | KK Nagar       |                     |
```

how to insert values in a new table in single column like sub1,sub2 and sub3 values group by id

Comment: `group_concat`?

Comment: can u be more specific on this?

Comment: Normalize this data or it is going to be a nightmare. See [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163)

Comment: I want all data in a new table from this table..like that
id | sub
1  | KK Nagar
1  | Alwartirunagar
1  | Porur

Comment: I know you like that. Because as a human you can visualize that. Unfortunately your users won't for the UX and performance. And you won't because your life will be one with find_in_set and tablescans and no use of indexes. And data modification will be nearly impossible. No one would architect it like that with a data architect. But be our guest.

Comment: Your data isn't normalized and you're basically asking for an unbounded pivot the `sub1` column.

Comment: Not to mention that as depicted there is no Primary Key to speak of. Maybe you have an unshown auto_increment. But your strategy is to just find the next 2 that doesn't have filled up slots and plop one in there. You are using a high performance beast of a RDBMS not some hokey spreadsheet or index card contraption. My recommendation is to spend some days on the basics of DB design then come back

Comment: I want like that id | subvalues          
1  | KK Nagar  
1  | Alwartirunagar       
1  | Valasaravakkam 
1  | Nandambakkam    
1  | Ramapuram   
1  | Meenambakkam  
1  | Ashok Nagar  
1  | Kodambakkam             
1  | Porur  
1  | Nungambakkam        
1  | Anna Nagar      
2  | West Mambalam   
2  | KK Nagar 
2  | Virugambakkam    
2  | T Nagar

Comment: can we get records from this table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use group concat with group by option like below - 
Your main table -

| id   | sub1           | sub2           | sub3         |

|    1 | kk nagar       | Alwartirunagar |              |
|    1 | Valasaravakkam | Nandambakkam   | Ramapuram    |
|    1 | Porur          | Meenambakkam   | Ashok Nagar  |
|    1 | Anna Nagar     | Kodambakkam    | Nungambakkam |
|    2 | West Mambalam  | Virugambakkam  | T Nagar      |
|    2 | KK Nagar       |                |              |

Now when you run a query - select id,group_concat(sub1,'|',sub2) from t1 group by id ; 
It will give you data like below

| id | group_concat(sub1,',',sub2,',',sub3)                                         |
|    1 | kk nagar,Alwartirunagar,,Valasaravakkam,Nandambakkam,Ramapuram,Porur,Meenambakkam,Ashok Nagar,Anna Nagar,Kodambakkam,Nungambakkam |
|    2 | West Mambalam,Virugambakkam,T Nagar,KK Nagar,,                                                        |

Now just insert this data in another table by below query 
 insert into t2 select id,group_concat(sub1,',',sub2,',',sub3) from t1 group by id ;

Now you will get data in t2 like below

| id   | grouped_sub |
|    1 | kk nagar,Alwartirunagar,,Valasaravakkam,Nandambakkam,Ramapuram,Porur,Meenambakkam,Ashok Nagar,Anna Nagar,Kodambakkam,Nungambakkam |

|    2 | West Mambalam,Virugambakkam,T Nagar,KK Nagar,,

Hope this will help you.

Note :- As question requirement are different -
Query -  insert into t2 select * from (select  id ,sub1 as subject  from t1 union select id,sub2 as subject from t1 union select id,sub3 as subject from t1 ) temp where subject !='' order by id ;

| id   | grouped_sub    |
+------+----------------+
|    1 | Nungambakkam   |
|    1 | Alwartirunagar |
|    1 | Ramapuram      |
|    1 | Porur          |
|    1 | Kodambakkam    |
|    1 | kk nagar       |
|    1 | Nandambakkam   |
|    1 | Ashok Nagar    |
|    1 | Anna Nagar     |
|    1 | Valasaravakkam |
|    1 | Meenambakkam   |
|    2 | West Mambalam  |
|    2 | T Nagar        |
|    2 | KK Nagar       |
|    2 | Virugambakkam  |

Comment: i am using group_concat and insert into 2nd table... i want to seperate rows..not like that .

Comment: Yes sure  ,Share your confusion

Comment: without comma in a same columns

Comment: Please share outout of one row what you want .

Comment: id | subvalues          
1  | KK Nagar  
1  | Alwartirunagar       
1  | Valasaravakkam 
1  | Nandambakkam    
1  | Ramapuram   
1  | Meenambakkam  
1  | Ashok Nagar  
1  | Kodambakkam             
1  | Porur  
1  | Nungambakkam        
1  | Anna Nagar      
2  | West Mambalam   
2  | KK Nagar 
2  | Virugambakkam    
2  | T Nagar

Comment: can u understand my requested output?

Comment: Is this only 2 rows with every column concated with id or these are total 15 rows

Comment: insert into t2 select * from (select  id ,sub1 as subject  from t1 union select id,sub2 as subject from t1 union select id,sub3 as subject from t1 ) temp where subject !='' order by id ; Please mark this answer and upvote if this works for you , For me it worked

Comment: what is the meaning of temp

Comment: It is just a temporary table name given .

Comment: SELECT campaign_id, sub1 AS sub_locations
FROM view_loc
WHERE sub1 !=  ""
UNION SELECT campaign_id, sub2 AS sub_locations
FROM view_loc
WHERE sub2 !=  ""
UNION SELECT campaign_id, sub3 AS sub_locations
FROM view_loc
WHERE sub3 !=  "" order by campaign_id

Comment: this code is working but ..when adding insert into command its not working..can u guide me

Comment: I added the insert command above and it is working fine for me , What error you are getting

Comment: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: INSERT INTO new_tbl SELECT * FROM(SELECT campaign_id,sub1 AS sub_locations,admin1 AS admin_locations,country AS country,locality AS locality FROM view_loc WHERE sub1!="" AND admin1!="" UNION SELECT campaign_id,sub2 AS sub_locations,admin2 AS admin_locations,country AS country,locality AS locality FROM view_loc WHERE sub2!="" AND admin2!="" UNION SELECT campaign_id,sub3 AS sub_locations,admin3 AS admin_locations,country AS country,locality AS locality FROM view_loc WHERE sub3!="" AND admin3!="" ORDER BY campaign_id) temp

Comment: Do your new_tbl contain same no of column which you are getting = 5

Comment: i am not understand ...my table (new_tbl) feilds are id,campaign_id,sub_locations,admin_locations,locality,country

Comment: Your new_tbl having 6 column while you are giving it 5 columns only so you are getting This error . Do like this INSERT INTO new_tbl (campaign_id,sub_locations,admin_locations,locality,country) SELECT * FROM(SELECT campaign_id

Comment: provide column name atleast Like my above comment ,Please mark my answer solved if this help you .

Comment: Please mark this answer as closed ,It will give me confidence to solve more queries

Comment: iam using like that INSERT INTO new_tbl( campaign_id, sub_locations, admin_locations, country, locality ) 
SELECT * 
FROM (

Comment: Please mark this answer as solves by clicking on "checkbox mark " just on left side of my answer .