# Designing a Mysql database with multiple values in a field

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a student doing my final year. I am supposed to create a database for my project such that it stores multiple values under a Skills column. For one one user id there can be multiple values in the skills field.

What is the best way to proceed ? I'm supposed to create in Mysql.

Comment: See normalisation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look it up.

Comment: I looked it up but it looked like it will take a lot of time. I'm on clock for my project. Is there any other way ?

Comment: It is the only sensible approach. Every other way will produce more problems later.

Comment: see the concept of junction/intersect and association tables like [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) . If you are under the gun, then doing it with CSV values will just slow down the dev anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to use two tables for this purpose.

```
UserTable:
Id    rest of the appropriate fields
1        ...........
2        ............

SkillSetTable:
id UserTable_id         skillName
1     1                   abcd
2     1                   pqrs
3     1                   hijk
4     1                   lmnop
```

Here you can use foreign key to point to UserTableid. That way you dont have to bother about number of skills

Comment: A surrogate key serves no useful purpose here

Comment: Which one are you referring to as surrogate key ?

Comment: id in SkillSetTable is surrogate

Comment: it is a common behavior to have primary key in a table, here id is primary key....  although you may think the rest two column can combine to be a composite key, yet it is up to designer's perspective

Comment: Yes. It's surrogate.