# Database design - dynmically store two tables foreign key for large records

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I have a student table and mentor table. User can manually assign set of students under a mentor dynamically. Once the mentor completes his mentorship, he can mark them as completed.

Student- Name, Address, Phone

Mentor-Name,Addres,Phone

Student_mentor- Student_id, Mentor_id

Problem is that when assigning list of students to mentor, there will be so many entries after a year or two. So is there any approach I can follow to overcome this problem?

Currently we have 50-60 mentors and each mentor can have 100 students under them for different subjects. So for example, a mentor can have 100 students for accounts and 100 students for commerce and so on.

This junction table "Student_mentor" will get populated on daily basis with a list of student for a mentor. May be after a month there might be 1M entries where only 10L entries might be useful. Is creating junction table is the only option I have?

Comment: What problem are we trying to solve here? Concern for the db server?

Comment: Too many  unwanted entries after a certain period of time. Maybe for a certain mentor there might be 10L entries after a year. Same mentor may get new 10L entries in the next year. I thought space related problem may arise.

Comment: N:M -> Junction table. Bridge table.

Comment: sounds like a teenie db. [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163/1816093) no multi-values / csv in a single column

Comment: Is junction table a good way to proceed for this problem? @wildplasser

Comment: The question is not clear. What is {accounts,commerce}, just another dimension in the mentor <--> student association? See Chris Date for 3NF -->> BCNF theory