# how to match two different columns in Mysql which has comma separated values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have two tables:

1. CampaignTable

which has following property

```
id , campaign ,user_group
```

example would be

```
1  8867116213  5,11,15,16,18,20
2  8867116214  0,8,22
```

Then I have another table called User Table

with following property

```
id emp_id  user_group
```

Example is like this

```
1  274  0,5,8,9,10,11,21,20
2  275  5,11,20
3  279  19,21,22,25
```

I have to join this table and create an Array which has campaign wise user

for example for campaign with id 1 it should give me

274, 275

How can I achieve this in Mysql

Thanks

Comment: You should normalize your database.

Comment: As @IvankaTodorova says, normalize your database. Proceeding with this design is going to make life extremely difficult.

Comment: Can you give me some idea How would I normalise? I mean which columns I should do

Comment: @IvankaTodorova can you help me to do that , WHat all columns should I normalise ?

Comment: see [Junction Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620163) . If you ever code like the above, I would never showcase it in an interview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definetely normalize your data. For example consider this kind of normalization which renders almost no change to your DB structure:

```
INSERT INTO CampaignTable
    (`campaign`, `user_group`)
VALUES
    (8867116213, 5),
    (8867116213, 11),
    (8867116213, 15),
    (8867116213, 16),
    (8867116213, 18),
    (8867116213, 20),
    (8867116214, 0),
    (8867116214, 8),
    (8867116214, 22)
;

INSERT INTO UserTable
    (`emp_id`, `user_group`)
VALUES
    (274, 0),
    (274, 5),
    (274, 8),
    (274, 9),
    (274, 10),
    (274, 11),
    (274, 21),
    (274, 20),
    (275, 5),
    (275, 11),
    (275, 20),
    (279, 19),
    (279, 21),
    (279, 22),
    (279, 25)
;
```

You could then fetch your data with a query as simple as that:

```
SELECT c.campaign, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.emp_id) FROM CampaignTable c 
JOIN UserTable u ON c.user_group = u.user_group
GROUP BY c.campaign
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e10cdb/10/0)